# How to retrieve artifacts from AZ pipeline triggered by PR in subsequent pipeline triggered by merge from the PR branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a developer raises a PR to a branch we have a branch policy that runs a build/test pipeline. If the pipeline is successful and the dev gets an approver they can merge to master.

There is a policy on master branch that kicks off a similar build/test/deploy pipeline. It would seem safe and quicker to pull the built artifact from the PR build pipeline since that actually built based off a git MERGE target to master. But I can't work out if there is an inherent relationship in Azure Devops between what is essentially the last green pipeline on a branch and the pipeline triggered by that branches merge to master.

Any pointers?